# Uncaught TypeError when loading store in button handler function

Tags: extjs6-classic

I got Uncaught TypeError when loading store in button handler function,
is there something wrong with my
Code:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Click me',
    handler: function() {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            autoLoad : true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url : 'MyUrl'
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

Error Message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: instance[configPropMap[name].names.get] is not a function
```

---

Debugger screenshots:

[`name` is `async`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NisVD.png)

[but `instance` has no `getAsync` function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuUj8.png)

Comment: The error occurred in ext-all-rtl-debug.js, I have no idea what the name is

Comment: Break on the error, look in the debugger.

Comment: `name` is `async`, but `instance` has no `getAsync` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution, use `syncajax` below instead of `proxy.ajax`.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.proxy.SyncAjax', {
extend : 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
alias  : 'proxy.syncajax',

config : {
    async : false
},

buildRequest : function() {
    var me      = this,
        request = me.callParent(arguments);

    request.defaultConfig.async = me.getAsync();
    request.getAsync = function() {
        request.getAsync = null;
        return me.getAsync();
    };

    return request;
}});
```